# Dispatching an Action is Throwing Error (React-Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux, redux-actions

I am new to react , i want to show/hide one error message based on a flag.

In calculator component

```
handleDealSizeChange({ target }){
  this.setState({
    [target.name]: target.value,
    dealType: 'patient'
  });
  this.props.doSearchClick(this.state.patientDealSize);
}
```

And connecting it via connect

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { patientDealSize='', dealType='' } = state;
  console.log("state" , state);
  return {
  patientDealSize,
  dealType
}

}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return {
    doSearchClick: (someName) =>{
      dispatch(setDealSize(someName))
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Calculator);
```

In actions

```
const setDealSizeSucess = (patientDealSize) =>{
    return {
        type: 'SET_DEAL_SIZE_SUCCESS',
        patientDealSize
    }
}

export const setDealSize = (patientDealSize) => dispatch => {

   dispatch(setDealSizeSucess(patientDealSize))
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

I am getting an error because that Uncaught TypeError: dispatch(...).catch is not a function . I am not understanding why is this issue occurring.

Comment: are you using any middleware

Comment: **dispatch** does not return a promise so you can’t chain **catch** to it.